# func start with PowerShell and Az.Storage strange error

Tags: powershell, azure-functions-core-tools

I run several Azure functions based on PowerShell. I love the local debugging feature, but lately I am experiencing a quite awkward error.

When running func start form the library containing my function, everything is fine, if it is the first time I start the function locally. However, if I stop and restart the local function, I get the following error:

```bsh
[5/2/2020 2:33:35 PM] EXCEPTION: Import-Module : Az.Storage doesn't support PowerShell Core versions lower than 6.2.4. Please upgrade to PowerShell Core 6.2.4 or higher.
[5/2/2020 2:33:35 PM] + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Az.Storage doesn't \u2026re 6.2.4 or higher.:String) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
[5/2/2020 2:33:35 PM] + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Az.Storage doesn't support PowerShell Core versions lower than 6.2.4. Please upgrade to PowerShell Core 6.2.4 or higher.,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
[5/2/2020 2:33:35 PM]
[5/2/2020 2:33:35 PM] Script stack trace:
[5/2/2020 2:33:35 PM]    at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\AxelBogAndersen\AppData\Local\AzureFunctions\TeamsAppBackend\ManagedDependencies\200501092203881.r\Az.Storage\1.14.0\Az.Storage.psm1: line 41
[5/2/2020 2:33:35 PM]
[5/2/2020 2:33:35 PM] System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Az.Storage doesn't support PowerShell Core versions lower than 6.2.4. Please upgrade to PowerShell Core 6.2.4 or higher.
[5/2/2020 2:33:35 PM]    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
```

I am running PowerShell 7.0, so it is higher then 6.2.4 - same error is produced in PowerShell 7.1 preview 2.

I have not defined any Az.Storage version in my function, so the newest version is loaded into the ManagedDependencies library. Currently that is version 1.14.0.

Once the error manifests, it is stable until I delete the entire folder in the ManagedDependencies library.

I would really like to avoid having to delete the dependencies package, because I have to wait for the download every time I do that. Downloading 256MB is time consuming annoying.

Just deleting the Az.Storage folder is not an option - the module is not re-loaded at next run and the entire session breaks. As a workaround I could live with deleting the Az.Storage and do a force update on the modules, if such a command exists.

I use AzTable in the mix, but I am not sure that has any significance.

I would be grateful for any kind of help to solve this very annoying issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In your Azure Function run.ps1 output the psVersion, it's most likely 6.2.3. If you used Chocolatey to install the Azure Function Core Tools in the config file there is an attribute called powershellHost, which uses Chocolatey's built-in powershell host.

```
feature name="powershellHost" enabled="true" setExplicitly="false" description="Use Chocolatey's built-in PowerShell host. Available in 0.9.10+." />
```

I had some trouble modifying the config file, so I just upgraded the package using Chocolatey and was able to use the Az modules.